# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Captions on Bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap 4 carousel that will show captions under the image, rather than on top of it. I'm able to get that done, but the issue I'm having is that the controls are taking the caption div's height into consideration when centering, so the vertical alignment is off.

Any advice on how to remedy this would be appreciated.

Codeply: http://codeply.com/go/lTDzvXp7IP

HTML

```
        <section class="media-gallery bg-light">            
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-11">
                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide captioned" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=16" alt="First slide">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image. I wonder what happens if this caption is very long? For example, what does it do to the credit?</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=136" alt="First slide">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=316" alt="First slide">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image. This caption is slightly different than the other, though idk why.</p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                       </a>
                       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                           <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                       </a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>       
   </section>
```

CSS

```
.media-gallery {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-prev, .carousel .carousel-control-next {
    font-size: 30px;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: you want move down below the image?

Comment: Yes - I'd like the captions to show up under the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated the carousel control absolute position to make it center horizontally. Now the control will not overlap the caption in any position.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var caption = $('div.carousel-item:nth-child(1) .media-content');
    $('.new-caption-area').html(caption.html());
    caption.css('display', 'none');

    $(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
        var caption = $('div.carousel-item:nth-child(' + ($(evt.relatedTarget).index() + 1) + ') .media-content');
        $('.new-caption-area').html(caption.html());
        caption.css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

```css
.media-gallery {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-next,
.carousel .carousel-control-prev {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel .carousel-control-next {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 5%;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel .carousel-control-next {
    font-size: 30px;
    background: none;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-next {
    right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="media-gallery bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-11">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide captioned" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=16" alt="First slide">
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image. I wonder what happens if this caption is very long? For example, what does it do to the credit?</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=136" alt="First slide">
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/667?r=316" alt="First slide">
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p class="media-credit"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="name">Person</span> / <span class="agency">Agency</span></p>
                                <div class="media-caption">
                                    <p>This is paragraph text that is the caption of the image. This caption is slightly different than the other, though idk why.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="new-caption-area"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hmm - it still looks like vertically the arrows aren't centered on the image, just horizontally... unless there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.2 and this worked for me. Create an empty paragraph block under your image and it pushes the caption with indicators below the image:

```
<!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->    
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="my-image.png" alt="First slide">
        <p id="block-under-image"></p>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p>My text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#block-under-image {
    background-color: black;
    height: 9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use proper z-index, default value is 1

```
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    z-index: 10000001;
}
```